# PTR entry in dns server

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

is there any faster way to add reverse and forward PTR entry in DNS server ?
thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Faster way than what?

You could use something like [mkrdns](http://www.mkrdns.org) to automatically generate reverse DNS zones from your forward zones. I've used mkrdns for a long time, it's a nice tool.

Answer (score 0):

Check out gadmintools

http://gadmintools.flippedweb.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=14&Itemid=33

its a gtk gui.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for public IPs, typically your provider is the only delegate for reverse DNS. You may be stuck requesting it from them every time you need to make a change.

If it's for internal IPs, they are just regular resource records, so you should use the same system you use now for forward addresses.